# Using jQuery post function, the returned link cannot have addClass function run on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
                <div id="add_to_library" class="add-library-wrapper">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="library-select" id="library-status-select" >Click</a>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a onclick="create_library_entry('Complete', 123, 124);" href="javascript:void(0)">Stuff</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

jQuery

```
                    $('#library-status-select').click(function() {
                        $(this).toggleClass('open');
                        $('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');                         
                    });     

                    function create_library_entry(status, user_id, anime_id) {

                        jQuery('#custom_lightbox').html('');

                        jQuery.post("/wp-content/themes/phanime/custom_functions/create_single_libraryEntry.php", {user_id : user_id, anime_id : anime_id, status : status}, function(data) {
                                //this is your response data from serv
                            console.log(data);
                            jQuery('#add_to_library').html(data);

                        });                         

                    }
```

So when I click on the `anchor` tag with the id of `library-status-select` it shows the div with the class `dropdown`. By adding an `open` class and so on. Once the dropdown shows it also has a link that does a jQuery post. The jQuery post returns it's result which in the `#add_to_library` id, where the link is contained. That link is replaced by another link that is returned from that `jQuery.post`. That link looks like this...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="library-select" id="library-status-select" >Click me updated</a>
```

It's essentially the same link with the same class / id but for some reason the jQuery.addClass / removeClass no longer works on the link that is returned from the jQuery.post. In other words the `open` class is not being added. If anyone knows exactly why this happens, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are replacing the contests you are dealing with dynamic contents so use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('#add_to_library').on('click', '#library-status-select', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know there was such a thing.